# Custom line break height in a textview

Tags: android, textview

I'm developping a chat application, and I have a textview to which I append each message formatted in HTML. So something like that :

```
textView.append(Html.fromHtml(message));
```

Example of a `message` : `<b><font color=\"#ababab\">User</font></b>: This is a test message<br />`

Now what I want to do is insert a custom line spacing between each `append`. Unfortunately, a line break (append "\n" or another `<br />`) is too high.

Also, tinkering with `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` does the exact opposite of what I want : it adds a spacing between lines of a single message that had to be broken down in multiple lines by the TextView, but it does nothing between each append.

I've also tried using `LineHeightSpan` but it didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried like `textView.append(Html.fromHtml("<br style=\"line-height:32px\">"));`

Comment: That didn't work, but I finally got it working by extending LineHeightSpan. The problem is that I was trying to apply it on the view's EditableText while I should have done it before, on the spannable.